# Is it possible to design figure using tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf

It is possible to design such complex figure using tikz and if possible then how because I know connect the lines but there so many links and where to find images of the nodes[image]

Comment: Yes it is possible. However if you don't come around with a concrete question about where exactly you're stuck (showing what you have tried already), chances are no one will help you. "Do this for me" questions aren't typically well received.

Comment: Btw.: The question "Is XY possible with TikZ" almost always has the answer "yes" :)

Comment: You could have a look at `\usetikzlibrary{mindmap}` and adopt it somehow. Here is a nice example: http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/servers/

Comment: I am struck to find the small figures in the node

Comment: You can find many similar looking symbols in `fontawesome`. They can be put in nodes and connected.

Answer (score 3):

This is a start. You can use symbols from e.g. `fontawesome`, define some styles for the nodes and pins and use positioning to relatively position these nodes.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,shapes.symbols}
\usepackage{fontawesome,ifsym}
\definecolor{myblue}{RGB}{101,151,203}
\definecolor{myred}{RGB}{204,80,67}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[c/.style={circle,node font=\Large},
    b/.style={c,fill=myblue},
    r/.style={c,fill=myred},
    w/.style={text=white},
    every pin edge/.style={bend left},
    every pin/.style={align=center},
    font=\sffamily\footnotesize,
    node distance=1em]
  % 
 \node[b,pin=left:Camera \& security] (camera) {\rotatebox{200}{\faVideoCamera}};
 \node[b,w,below=of camera,xshift=1ex,pin=left:{Connected\\ Vehicles}] (car) {\faCar};
 \node[r,w,below=of car,xshift=-1.5ex,pin=below left:Retail Industry] 
    (industry) {\faShoppingBasket};
 \node[r,w,right=of camera,yshift=1ex,pin=above left:Smart Cities] (cities) {\faBuildingO}; 
 \node[cloud, draw,below right=of cities, aspect=2,align=center] {Blockchain};
 \draw (camera) -- (car) -- (industry); 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: To the downvoter: what is your problem with this post? Or is it just a random downvote because, say, you do not want such questions to get any answers?

Comment: And...I add a upvote. Very nice the picture.