# Path Diagram Using Tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I wanna make a diagram like this:[image]

How can I draw such a “jointed” path?

Comment: Could you perhaps at least show what you tried so far? There are several ways to make such a diagram. Help us help you by showing a bit of your code. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to use `tikz-cd`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}[/tikz/column 1/.style={column sep=4em},
    /tikz/column 4/.style={column sep=4em},
    every arrow/.append style={-stealth,semithick}]
 & \text{divisor} \arrow[rr]& & \text{existence} 
 \arrow[dr,rounded corners=1em,to path={-- ++ (4em,0) |- (\tikztotarget)}]& \\
 \text{UFD} 
 \arrow[ur,rounded corners=1em,to path={-- ++ (4em,0) |- (\tikztotarget)}]
 \arrow[dr,rounded corners=1em,to path={-- ++ (4em,0) |- (\tikztotarget)}]
 & & & & \text{UFD} \\
 & \text{GCD}\arrow[r] & \text{primeness}\arrow[r,"" {marking,name=p,pos=0.8}] &
 \arrow[from=1-2,to=p,dash,out=0,in=180] 
 \text{uniqueness} 
 \arrow[ur,rounded corners=1em,to path={-- ++ (4em,0) |- (\tikztotarget)}]& \\
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Why there was an unjustified downvote? :-(

Comment: @Sebastiano Presumably the same user as the one responsible for [this downvote](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/541395/is-it-possible-to-design-figure-using-tikz/541401#541401), probably a user who started their career here with a question which also required significant efforts by the answerer (and at this point thanked the answerer for the support...). It is sad, as usual, but not much one can do.

Comment: I never liked childish behaviour and wickedness. I made up for your beautiful answers. I can do no more.

Comment: @Sebastiano Thanks! I think the best option is to ignore those. They mainly want to have attention. Let's just deny them that attention. It is usually possible to make an educated guess who is behind these downvotes. So ignoring them also means ignoring their posts, if they do not want to participate in constructive voting there is no reason to upvote their posts.